# How to save only one column in a SELECT statement with multiple fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to build a SQL statement that selects 4 columns from a table but only saves one of them.

```
... UNION SELECT field1,field2,field3 INTO OUTFILE '/path' FROM table WHERE condition
```

The result is

```
field1,field2,field3
```

However I only want to save field3.

```
field3
```

I have tried:

```
 ... UNION SELECT NULL,NULL,field3 INTO OUTFILE '/path' FROM table WHERE condition
```

But it results on the follwing:

```
\n \n field3
```

I cannot remove the field1 and field2 because the SQL statement is to be concatenated with other SQL statements.

Thank you for your help

Note : I am using MySQL

Comment: use instead empty string ''

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling to fin the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the main query a subquery before union.

```
SELECT field3 
FROM (
   {other SQL statements}
) other_sql_statements
UNION
SELECT field3 
INTO OUTFILE '/path' 
FROM table 
WHERE condition
```

In MySQL 8 with CTE:

```
WITH other_sql_statements AS (
   {other SQL statements}
)
SELECT field3
FROM other_sql_statements
UNION
SELECT field3 
INTO OUTFILE '/path' 
FROM table 
WHERE condition
```